# How to configure custom instantiation in EclipseLink

Tags: java, eclipselink

I'm doing some nonstandard things with code generation in a Hibernate project, and now I'm trying to port it to EclipseLink. In Hibernate, I successfully implemented all of these with Tuplizers. In EclipseLink, I think Descriptors are what I should be working with, but they have so many methods and such terse documentation that I'm having trouble figuring out if the features I need even exist, much less how to use them.

I need the following configuration capabilities:

1. For an `@Entity` class `Foo`, instantiate it with a generated subclass `Bar`, which augments it with behavior EclipseLink doesn't need to know about. I think I've got this part done, using `ClassDescriptor.useFactoryInstantiationPolicy()`.
2. For any instance of `Bar`, generated subclass of `Foo`, save it to the database as a `Foo` entity. I haven't gotten far enough to be able to test whether this part even needs custom configuration.
3. For an `@Embedded` field `baz` in `@Entity` class `Foo`, instantiate the `@Embeddable` with a `Foo`-specific generated subclass that augments it with behavior EclipseLink doesn't need to know about. Or, preferably, just use the instance the `Foo` constructor made. This is what I'm currently stuck on. I tried `ClassDescriptor.getMappingForAttributeName("baz").getReferenceDescriptor().useFactoryInstantiationPolicy()`, but `getReferenceDescriptor()` returns null. Further, `getMappingForAttributeName()` returns null if the attribute is inherited.
4. If "just take what the `Foo` constructor made" isn't an option for point 3, call a post-initialization method on each `Foo` instance after filling in its fields, which will give `baz` a reference to the enclosing `Foo` instance to enable some of the augmented behavior.

How can I set these up, preferably with programmatic calls at runtime? Annotations on the generated classes could be acceptable, or possibly generating an additional xml file, but adding anything to `Foo` itself would be a last resort.

Comment: Your Embeddable has its own descriptor that you can lookup from the session rather then through Foo's mapping.  Option 2 should not need special handling, as any subclass is persisted as an instance of its parent unless it has its own descriptor or is its own JPA entity.

Comment: @Chris For embeddables I'm aware of that, but the augmented behavior is different and specific to each `Foo` class, and in some cases even to different `baz` fields in the same class and of the same embeddable type. Settings in a session-wide context-free descriptor for the embeddable on its own won't do what I need.